# Can't send Integer to exec function through stdin redirection. C language

Tags: c, process, pipe

This is an academic exercise. I'm supposed to read an integer from the father process, send it to the child, and the child is supposed to call the exec function of factorial (which must read from stdin and write on stdout). Father must show the result of the exec function.

Apparently the exec function is reading nothing but garbage (random big values) from the stdin redirection I've made. Can't figure out why.

Here is the code of main program and exec function (factorial):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER 80

int main (){

    int pipeFatherChild[2], pipeChildFather[2],i;
    pid_t pid;

    if(pipe(pipeFatherChild)==-1 || pipe(pipeChildFather)==-1){
        perror("pipe Error!");
        return -1;
    }

    pid = fork();

    if(pid<0){
        perror("fork Error!");
        return -1;
    }



    if(pid>0){//father
        int value;
        char result[MAX_BUFFER];

        close(pipeFatherChild[0]);
        close(pipeChildFather[1]);

        printf("Please insert nunber to calculate factorial:\n");
        scanf("%d",&value);

        write(pipeFatherChild[1],&value,sizeof(int));
        close(pipeFatherChild[1]);

        wait(NULL);//wait for child

        int ret;
        while((ret=read(pipeChildFather[0],&result,MAX_BUFFER)!=0)){
            printf("PAI DIZ: %s\n", result);
        }

        close(pipeChildFather[0]);


    }else{//child

        close(pipeFatherChild[1]);

        dup2(pipeFatherChild[0],0);
        close(pipeFatherChild[0]);

        close(pipeChildFather[0]);

        dup2(pipeChildFather[1],1);
        close(pipeChildFather[1]);

        execl("./factorial", "factorial");

        perror("Child Error\n");


    }


    return 0;
}
```

Factorial program:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int factorial(int n){
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    return n * factorial(n-1);
}


int main(){

    int n;

    fscanf(stdin,"%d", &n);
    fprintf(stdout,"Factorial of %d is %d\n", n, factorial(n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You `scanf()` the number in the parent, then write the *binary representation of the int* to the pipe, and `fscanf()` it again in the child. That's not going to work.

Comment: Thanks. What should I do to correct that?

Comment: What EOF said.  As an aside, it's odd, albeit not necessarily wrong, to `wait()` for the child before reading its response from the pipe.  Doing it in this order is risky because if the child blocks while writing to the pipe then the parent and child will deadlock -- the child cannot proceed and therefore does not exit until some space is made in the pipe's buffer (as a result of the parent reading from it), but the parent will not read until the child exits.  Surely your pipe's buffer is large enough to avoid deadlock in this case, but you should not learn bad habits.

Comment: @CANHOTTO, if you write with `write()` then you should read with `read()`.  If you want to read with `scanf()` then you should write with `printf()`.